# Project Phoenix installation for Windows

Tags: wxpython

The Project Phoenix site says "If you have a modern up to date version of Windows and use the binary installer for wxPython found below, you probably don’t need anything else."

I looked below and don't find the installer.  Where is it?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean [this page](http://www.wxpython.org/download-2.6.4.0.php)? There seems to be a whole section for it called `Prebuilt Binaries`...

Answer (score 2):

Phoenix is not officieally released yet, however there are snapshot builds which you can install with pip.

[wxPython wiki - how to install](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython)